# Rails - Validate nested attribute on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have two models `Customer` and `Item`, Customer `has_many :items` and Item `belongs_to :customer` and `Customer accepts_nested_attributes_for :items`. An item can be returned or not returned, but what I need to do, is validate on create that the `item.number` is not repeated for the not_returned items. My validation is as follows:

```
def unique_number
    if Item.not_returned.find_all_by_number(self.number).to_a.size > 0
       errors.add(:number, "duplicate number, please use another")
    end
end

def self.not_returned
   where("returned = false")    
end
```

But it doesn't work if I add two newly created items with the same number, not sure why, but I need to validate this even when two records are being created at the same time, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Curious question, why is where("returned = false") a string? What is returned?

Comment: returned is an attribute of item, and that's just a scope to get all the non-returned items

Comment: Is that a column called returned that is a boolean, shouldn't it be where(:returned => false) or where(returned: false) depending on the rails version

Comment: yeah I guess it's the same thing